# Рисование линий на html5/css

Tags: html, css, canvas

Подскажите как можно нарисовать такие линии и поместить внутри текст как на этой картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обыскал весь интернет, где-то есть только квадраты, а где только линии на `canvas`, пытался сделать под себя, не получилось. Мне нужны именно 2 этих прямых угла. Помогите их нарисовать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общий принцип такой:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
span{
  padding:5px 15px;
  position:relative;
  Font-size:20px;
}
span:before,
span:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}
span:before{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-width:1px 0 0 1px;
}
span:after{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  border-width:0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Text</span>
```

Comment: свой ответ удалил так как он похож)

Comment: @zhurof Спасибо большое!